# Why is request.getRemoteUser() returning the tomcat windows service account sometimes

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, gwt, windows-authentication

I'm trying to get windows authentification to work with a 3rd party application developped with GWT. 
I'm hosting the app with tomcat, on a windows server.  I access the site through an IIS proxy (installed following the tomcat's documentation).

If i modify a .jsp of the webapp to display "<%= request.getRemoteUser() %>" , I get the username i'm hopping for, my windows account.

But the webapp authenticate me with the account I installed the Tomcat windows service with on the server.

In the (decompiled) source code of the webapp, i see a call to the exact same "request.getRemoteUser()" , so I wonder where can be the difference.

Here are the decompiled classes :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class RemoteUserLoginProvider
  extends BaseRequestLoginProvider
{
  public String extractLoginFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    return request.getRemoteUser();
  }
}
```

And :

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Provider; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public abstract class BaseRequestLoginProvider
  implements Provider<String>
{
  @Inject
  private Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider;

  public abstract String extractLoginFromRequest(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest);

  public String get()
  {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)this.requestProvider.get();
    String userlogin = extractLoginFromRequest(request);

    return userlogin;
  }
}
```

Could my problem be linked to this bug on google's guice : https://github.com/google/guice/issues/780  ?

If so, is there any work around ?

Comment: I rephrased my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664679/request-getremoteuser-returns-a-different-login-in-jsp-than-in-a-servlet-filt , after additional testing to rule out the possibility that the problem was with guice/gwt.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()` normally just returns the same value as the CGI `REMOTE_USER` variable, which is the username from HTTP Basic Authentication. It sounds like you want it to be a different value, which means something is modifying the `HttpServletRequest` object. Most likely this is accomplished by a Servlet Filter.

If that Guice bug is the culprit, it's easy enough to work around: simply ensure that `GuiceFilter` is installed *after* whatever Filter is authenticating the request and modifying the `HttpServletRequest` object.

As a general rule of thumb, I don't think modifying the request like that is a good idea, precisely because it's so hard to debug when something goes wrong. If instead you had a `@RequestScoped` provider that extracted the value(s) you want out of the request and did whatever authentication you need, you could consume the user information by dependency injection instead. Or, more generally: always prefer to create new (preferably immutable) values rather than mutating existing objects -- it makes the control flow much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getRemoteUser()` returns the name of the user is derived from the authorization header sent by the client before the user name is mapped to a `Windows account`. If you have an authentication filter installed on your Web server that maps incoming users to accounts, use `LOGON_USER` to view the mapped user name.

[IIS server variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602%28v%3Dvs.90%29)

Comment: If you did not find the above solution helpful, you may also go through this article.
https://blogs.oracle.com/wssfc/handling-proxy-server-authentication-requests-in-java